# How to get the last project search results?

Tags: search, doom

When searching in project with `+default/search-project` after opening a result. How do I get back to the previous search results? And ideally to the same position in the results list?

The usecase: Search for all occurences of "xyz" in the project. Pick the first result and open the buffer. Make changes and continue with the next item from the search results.

I use Doom with `vertico` if that matters.

Comment: I am not yet using `vertico` nor Doom, but I did find that there exists [vertico-repeat.el](https://github.com/minad/vertico/issues/38#issuecomment-877100804) for this (well for getting the previous results. For your specific usecase, I guess you could make a request for adding functionality that supports the workflow, e.g. an option to have a persistent vertico buffer)